# Unable to change my display name

Tags: support, profile-page

I recently completed the About Me section of my profile, and now I do not see any option to change my name or my profile details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your user picture up close to top right to load up your user profile. You should see an "Edit Profile and Settings option. If that is not there, maybe try logging out and back in again.

[image: Screenshot of profile page showing location of edit button]

Comment: Tried logging back in and out again, still can’t see any edit profile section

Comment: Shut Down my computer and restarted it and now am finally able to change my display name! Guess it must've been a bug in my browser or something